# What is mixed methods research?

Tags: research-design, mixed-type-data, qualitative

I tried to look up the answer but am confused by what this means exactly.

It seems like one is a precursor to the other, thus you need both to conduct a study unless you're working with existing data. For example, qualitative data seems to be later be quantified in order to run any sort of analysis. Quantitative data needs to come from somewhere (interviews, research etc.) otherwise you won't have data.

Comment: A classic, originary statement of mixed methods was made by the great, late Donald Campbell and his co-author, Donald Fiske, in a 1959 psychometrics paper, back in the days when psychology still had some research integrity *Convergent and discriminant validation by the multitrait-multimethod matrix* https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1960-00103-001 Their approach is Pearson correlational but there's no reason more recent dependence metrics couldn't be plugged in to update it, among other possibilities. More recent work has been done, e.g., in human resource talent mgmt

Comment: Your edit contains the answer to your query. Interviews, focus groups, quantitative questionnaires and surveys, etc. are *mixed methods* if more than one of them is employed in a study design.

Comment: thanks, the sites explaining it makes it seem more like one explains the other rather than being merely unprocessed vs processed data.

Comment: Such sites are, obviously, all too often so badly explained and worded as to be incomprehensible...they're like Cliff Notes for quants.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, there are two types of data analysis: quantitative and qualitative. The first type deals with 'numbers' and the second with 'non-numbers' (text, words, images etc). Classical quantitative analysis includes descriptive statistics, statistical inference and hypothesis tests. In turn, classical qualitative methods includes interviews, focus groups and content analysis. Mixed methods - sometimes called multimethodology - uses both approaches in the same research/study to answer a research question.

It is not true that one is a precursor to the other - they can be used in any order or at the same time. Under a mixed method approach, each type is treated as being of equal value to inform. A key theory around using mixed methods is the idea of triangulation that attempts to resolve a research problem using multiple approaches.

There are different ways that mixed methods can be expressed - some research may emphasize quantitative analysis while qualitative is less prominent or vice versa. There is a large range of mixtures in between - something like 24 permutations of mixed methods according to one article! Mixed methods is powerful as it provides a combination of methods to help ensure that the research question is appropriately answered.

There is an extensive body of literature on mixed methods that is increasing. Start with the references on Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimethodology#Further_reading) as a springboard into the topic.